# Can't start activities marked as MainLauncher in parallel

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on a Xamarin Android project where I'd like to have activities as different starting points (e.g. `app1` and `app2`).
To achieve this I've added the option "MainLauncher = true" to the Activity-Attribute of those activities which *seemed* to work fine in the beginning:

```
[Activity(
    Label = "App1", 
    Icon = "@drawable/app1_app_icon", 
    MainLauncher = true
)]
```

The issue now is, that if I open `app1`, go back to the menu screen - withtout closing it - and open `app2` at the same time, the already running `app1` is displayed. `App2` is not started. This is not what I've expected to happen.

Is there a way to make it work in a way that `app2` gets also started at the same time as `app1` is running?

I know that it is possible to start one activity multiple times but this is not what I want. Each activity should only be started once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to define an additional attribute called `TaskAffinity` defining the activity that should be opened.

For `App1` you would define:

```
[Activity(
    Label = "App1", 
    Icon = "@drawable/app1_app_icon", 
    MainLauncher = true,
    TaskAffinity = "com.company.project.actApp1"
)]
```

For `App2` you just change the string to:

```
[Activity(
    Label = "App2", 
    Icon = "@drawable/app2_app_icon", 
    MainLauncher = true,
    TaskAffinity = "com.company.project.actApp2"
)]
```

There is also another stackoverflow question that treats this topic of TaskAffinity:

[Two main activities in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526805/two-main-activities-in-androidmanifest-xml)

The best explanation of what TaskAffinity I could find is also a stackoverflow question:

[Android Task Affinity Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872989/android-task-affinity-explanation)