# Multiple launchers for one Application with API 17

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have my application and I would like to have two different launchers that each launch different activities. They should all be bundled into one apk and *not* two separate applications. I know this is possible, example in the XKCD Browser on the Google play store. I have already tried implementing this segment in the second activity I need to be in the launcher:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This results in the first activity declared as MAIN to be launched when clicking the second launcher. I have also tried:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_NAME"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

As well as:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name=ACTIVITY_NAME"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Which achieves the same result. I need this to function down to API 17. Ideas?

Comment: Do you have the default category defined anywhere in the manifest? `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> `

Comment: Also, you might need to set the `android:taskAffinity` for both Activities to avoid clicking on the second launcher to start the first app when it's already in memory.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526805/two-main-activities-in-androidmanifest-xml

Answer (score 1):

You should have a main activity with:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And any other activity with only the `category` part:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This results in a system Toast saying "App isn't installed"

Comment: @Iambic that's quite strange. Be sure to use only one `MAIN` intent filter and re-install your app. If the issue persists, I imagine there might be problems depending on your activity code. E.g., is your second activity linked to a proper Activity class? Please post your manifest file.

Comment: Re-installed the application and the second activity does not appear as a launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put the same date frome place where your call intent for start app

```
<activity
android:name="com.spectrum.media.activity.InitializationScreen" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
                <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
</intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="-1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
           </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-->category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />;-->
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And parse this scheme in first activity and run others if necessary.