# Android Apk generating multiple files after installation on System (Mobile)

Tags: android

My apk file generating multiple files after installation on the system as shown in screenshot. Please help me, what to do??

[image]

Comment: I saw you run on a emulator, try to run on a real device to see if your problem still occurs

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file if you are using `Android Studio`

Comment: I think you have same app with 3 different code  & package name otherwise its inpossible

Comment: Thanks guys, i got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is one App having multiple activities marked as action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER:

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleActivity1" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ExampleActivity2" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

See also this SO question: [Two main activities in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526805/two-main-activities-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Comment: Oh Thanks Robert, i got it.