# Multi icon in screen Android

Tags: android, icons, screen

I created two Activity in android project. After build, in screen emulator has two [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV46l.png) in the screen. What can be done to get single icon?

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kt3.chientran.chat">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: paste your code

Comment: paste your manifest.xml here.

Comment: i have just creat activity, so code is default in android studio

Comment: @MayankPandya I have updated manifest file.

Comment: Remove <intent-filter> from .Activity2

Comment: The LAUNCHER intent filter is what determines what shows up in the app drawer/launcher. That is why you get two icons shown up.Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526805/two-main-activities-in-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: choose one from the two activities as LAUNCHER

Comment: exactly, when create activity, I checked in 2 option in panel, am so stupid.
Thank all for you help. :))