# How do we find main activity in AndroidManifest.xml using python?

Tags: android, python, xml-parsing

I am new to Python, so this might be a way too simple question. I am trying to parse AndroidManifest.xml file to find the main activity.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.heartrateapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MonitorActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SubmitActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The activity with the following intent is the main activity.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Python parser:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

  data = ''
  with open('AndroidManifest.xml','r') as f:
    data = f.read()
  dom = parseString(data)
  activities = dom.getElementsByTagName('activity')
  perms = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')

  for activity in activities:
    print activity.getAttribute('android:name')
    print activity.getElementsByTagName('intent-filter')
 for perm in perms:
    print perm.getAttribute('android:name')
```

How can I find the main activity? For now I have used print to check. I would like to create an object to store the Main Activity, intents, services, perms. etc. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: "activity with the following intent is the main activity" is incorrect, there can be several with category Launcher

Comment: @NickCardoso thanks! Should it be `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` ?

Comment: Yes - and in case you need it - [other help with intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) (Sorry, I dont know any python to actually answer you)

Comment: @NickCardoso i followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526805/two-main-activities-in-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: Sure, the question code is misleading then. action.MAIN = Main entry point, category.LAUNCHER = show activity shortcut in app drawer and optional category.DEFAULT = normal intents (vs looking for an item to open a link with etc.) Additionally, when parsing remember there can be multiple category and action items in each activity

Comment: @NickCardoso thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for finding main activity. How do I add to a class instead of using print?

```
for activity in activities:
    print activity.getAttribute('android:name')
    intents = activity.getElementsByTagName('intent-filter')
    for intent in intents:
        actions = intent.getElementsByTagName('action')
        for action in actions:
            if  action.getAttribute('android:name') == 'android.intent.action.MAIN':
                print action.getAttribute('android:name')
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you're looking for the Activity which contains a `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` intent filter.

Being as there is supposed to be only one of these in a manifest, you can stop when you find the first one.

So from your sample and my knowledge of other languages I'd expect your code to look like

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

  data = ''
  with open('AndroidManifest.xml','r') as f:
      data = f.read()
      dom = parseString(data)
      activities = dom.getElementsByTagName('activity')
      perms = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')

      mainactivity = None #or whatever python null is

      for activity in activities:
          filters = activity.getElementsByTagName('intent-filter')
          for intent in filters:
              if intent.getAttribute('android:name') == "android.intent.action.MAIN"
                  mainactivity = activity
                  break #end intent loop 
           if mainactivity
              break #end activity loop

      print mainactivity.getAttribute('android:name')
```